# str.replace won't work within a function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

Why is this function not returning the result of the replace?

```
def replacechar(str):
    str.replace("č","c")
    str.replace("a","y")
    return str
p= "abcdč"
replacechar(p)
print(p)
```

output:

```
abcdč
```

Comment: you just have to assign it back to `str` (which is a very bad variable name btw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.replace` is not an inplace operation. It returns a string. The good news is that your function will work with minimal modification.

```
def replacechar(string):
    return string.replace("č","c").replace("a","y")
```

Next, you will need to assign the return value back to `p`:

```
p = replacechar(p)
```

Also, don't use `str` to name an object because you already have something with that name.

---

Alternatively, have you considered `str.translate`?

```
_TAB = str.maketrans({'č' : 'c', 'a' : 'y'})
def replacechar(string):
    return string.translate(_TAB)
```

Answer (score 3):

`replace()` returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new.

`str.replace` has to be assigned back to `str` in order to return the updated string.

But in your above function you are not overwriting the variable `str`.

```
def replacechar(str):
    str = str.replace("č","c")
    str = str.replace("a","y")
    return str
p= "abcdč"
print replacechar(p)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
ybcdc
abcdč
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what i wanted to know.

Comment: @cvizrada If this is what you wanted to know, then [Ev. Kounis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730870/str-replace-wont-work-within-new-defined-function/45730988#comment78419379_45730870) comment said it.

Comment: Unfortunately I somehow missed his comment in notifications, so i saw this first. I am new here, sorry.

Comment: @cvizrada As an answer this might explain what is wrong but it is incomplete, because it does not address all the problems with your code.

Comment: I replaced the "str" with "word", and i updated variable. What more problems i have with the code?

Comment: @hope94 I was speaking about this answer, that didn't mention those problems. You're good now!